# Using WSS4CF with <cfhttp>

Tags: soap, coldfusion

This is a bit of a stretch and I'm hoping someone with WSS4CF experience will know exactly what I'm on about.

We are attempting to access a remote webservice, requiring WS Security with username/password. After playing around with SOAP + `<cfhttp>` and running into class issues, my colleague suggested I take a look at [WSS4CF](http://wss4cf.riaforge.org/wiki/). It seemed just what I needed to avoid needing to deal with those additional jar files etc.

There is no example provided and I noticed that the cfc ([view here](http://code.google.com/p/training-govt-au/wiki/secureWebservice)) seems to be configured to work with something like a dotNet SOAP service where you simply call a method with arguments, e.g.

```
<cfinvoke 
            webservice="https://service.gov.au/OrgService.svc?WSDL" 
            refreshwsdl="true"
            method="Search"
            returnvariable="aSearch">
                <cfinvokeargument name="request" value="#arguments.sXML#"/>
        </cfinvoke>
```

WSS4CF works by first creating a secure web service, then making the request within that secure environment. I tried the above code and it doesn't work (didn't expect it to). The service is expecting an xml packet, not a method call with arguments.

Rather than fiddle with that, I need to configure it to work with cfhttp where we pass an xml envelope in a cfhttpparam, e.g. as follows:

```
<cfhttp
    url="/service.gov.au/OrgService.svc?WSDL"
    method="post">

    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/soap+xml" /><!---text/xml--->
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="http://service.gov.au/services/IOrgService/Search"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept-encoding" value="no-compression" />
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#trim(sXML)#"/>

</cfhttp>
```

Any help to do this would be appreciated. I'm not expecting people to research the library unless they're interested. More hoping that someone whose worked with WSS4CF can provide some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not using WS-Security itself, [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630394/coldfusion-how-to-authenticate-webservice-getshipmentsimplequote-of-wwex/10651618#10651618) may help you do what you're after, assuming that you can send the WS-Security packet in the message headers (which wikipedia assures me you can). In that approach, you use cfinvoke, but add a header, which in your case would be the ws-security header. You'd still have to assemble the header yourself, but I think that is possible